# How to Serialize a list in java?

Tags: java, serialization, collections, apache-commons

I would like to deep clone a List. for that we are having a method

```
// apache commons method. This object should be serializable
SerializationUtils.clone ( object )
```

so now to clone my List i should convert that to serializable first. Is it possible to convert a List into Serializable list?

Answer (score 184, accepted):

All standard implementations of `java.util.List` already implement `java.io.Serializable`.

So even though `java.util.List` itself is not a subtype of `java.io.Serializable`, it should be safe to cast the list to `Serializable`, as long as you know it's one of the standard implementations like `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`.

If you're not sure, then copy the list first (using something like `new ArrayList(myList)`), then you know it's serializable.

Comment: Why would anyone ever want to cast anything to Serializable? Serializable is only a marker interface; casting something to Serializable isn't useful.

Comment: Because `SerializationUtils.clone()` requires an argument on type `Serializable`, and so if your variable is of type `List`, you'll need to cast it.

Comment: @Jesper: It's a marker interface that says it's safe to serialize the class.  Android uses the Serializable interface for many things; passing along intent extras, shared preferences, etc.

Comment: Yes, I found this question when searching Android solutions. My addition is, `List<MyClass> myObjs = new ArrayList<MyClass>();` doesn't meet the `Serializable`, but `ArrayList<MyClass> myObjs = new ArrayList<MyClass>();` does.

Comment: @EviSong because the `interface` `List` is **not** `serializable.` Your declaring your variable of type `List`.

Comment: If I have a bean that contains a List of serializable objects, should I put a check in the setter to make sure the List is serializable since I won't know what kind of list is being set?

Comment: @Adam It might be best to guarantee safety at compile-time instead by using the signature `<T extends List<Foo> & Serializable> setFooList(T list)`, which requires your caller to pass you an instance of some List implementation that is also Serializable.

Answer (score 36):

As pointed out already, most standard implementations of `List` are serializable. However you have to ensure that the objects referenced/contained within the list are *also* serializable.

Comment: As pointed out already, `List` is an interface that does not extend `Serializable` or any interface that does so. `List`s that are not serializable may not be common in standard libraries, but that does not make the first sentence right.

Comment: List is not but implementation classes like ArrayLists are serializable. You can use them.

Answer (score 15):

*List* is just an interface. The question is: is your actual *List* implementation serializable? Speaking about the standard *List* implementations (*ArrayList*, *LinkedList*) from the Java run-time, most of them actually are already.