# Serialize list of employees in java

Tags: java, class, serialization, object

I have a simple employee class:

```
class Employee {

    private int     id;
    private String  firstName;
    private String  lastName;
    private String  streetAddress;
    private String  city;
    private String  state;
    private String  zip;
    private String  cellularPhoneNumber;
    private String  homePhoneNumber;

    public Employee(int id, String firstName, String lastName, String streetAddress, String city, String state, String zip, String cellularPhoneNumber, String homePhoneNumber) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.streetAddress = streetAddress;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.zip = zip;
        this.cellularPhoneNumber = cellularPhoneNumber;
        this.homePhoneNumber = homePhoneNumber;
    }
}
```

How could I go about serializing multiple employees to a file? I know how to serialize one object, but how could I have multiple ones?

Could somebody point me in the right direction or provide a sample of serializing multiple objects? Would I be better off using a database like SQLite?

Much thanks in advanced.

Comment: First result on this site for "java serialize list": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387954/how-to-serialize-a-list-in-java

Comment: See here on sun's site http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/

Answer (score 4):

The collections in `java.util` are Serializable. So if you make your Employee class implement `Serializable`, then put your employees in an ArrayList, then you can serialize the list and it will save the employees.

HSQLDB and H2 are in-memory databases implemented in Java that may be good alternatives to SQLite (meaning easier to use from a Java program). For general learning purposes using a database is a more practical skill, serializing things is not something I do a lot (when my code does use serialized classes the actual serialization is left up to the environment, such as when storing things in an HttpSession).

Comment: It's not for a company or anything, I'm just playing around, trying to learn how to work with classes. Thanks! I'll play around with the array list.

Answer (score 2):

1. `add(..)` the objects to a `List` - for example an `ArrayList`
2. serialize the list

As for your SQLite question - I can't tell. Generally, you shouldn't use serialization as a database storage, but if your application is simple, it should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Employee> e = new ArrayList<Employee>() {{

add(new Employee(...));
add(new Employee(...));
add(new Employee(...));
add(new Employee(...));
add(new Employee(...));

}};


Employee implements Serializable {

.....
}
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to go for serialization using Jackson , JSON .

The benefit is that after serializing, you can atleast see your Data. Java Serialization is limiting in many aspects.