# How to write multiple objects to file?

Tags: java, file, object

I want to write multiple objects to a file, but the problem is that I dont have all the objects to write at once. I have to write one object and then close the file, and then maybe after sometime I want to add another object to the same file.

I am currently doing it as
 `FileOutputStream("filename", true)` 
so that it will append the object to the end of file and not overwrite it. But I get this error :

> java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC

any ideas how can I solve this issue ?

Thanks,

Comment: if you do not need random access to the objects, @Jon's answer is on the mark. However if you do (i.e. dont want to read all of them), you need directory at the beginning (or end) of the file w/ some the offset, some key to and length. Alternatively just use separate files, nowadays file systems (esp ext4) are pretty good at organizing even small files efficiently (esp if you have SSD :D )

Comment: Thank you everyone, The solution proposed by Jon seems robust but its too complicated for me, so I guess I'll settle for your solution (creating separate files for each new object) or EJP's solution of reading old objects and then write all the old+new objects to the file gain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't append different ObjectOutputStreams to the same file. You would have to use a different form of serialization, or read the file in and write out all the objects plus the new objects to a new file.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to segment the file into individual messages. When you want to write a message, first serialize it to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. Then open the file for appending with `DataOutputStream` - write the length with `writeInt`, then write the data.

When you're reading from the stream, you'd open it with `DataInputStream`, then repeatedly call `readInt` to find the length of the next message, then `readFully` to read the message itself. Put the message into `ByteArrayInputStream` and then deserialize from that.

Alternatively, use a nicer serialization format than the built-in Java serialization - I'm a fan of [Protocol Buffers](http://protobuf.googlecode.com) but there are lots of alternatives available. The built-in serialization is too brittle for my liking.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `serialize`/`deserialize` the `List<T>`. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387954/how-to-serialize-a-list-in-java) stackoverflow thread.