# How to receive data via sockets retrieved through Result Set?

Tags: java, sockets, resultset

```
Statement st=(Statement) sqlcon.createStatement();
ResultSet p=st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `chat`.`online_users`");
```

I have got the data from the database through the object of ResultSet but when i am sending it to the client through sockets it is giving an error. It is not serializable. How to send data and receive data retrieved through ResultSet across socket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the data from the `ResultSet`, push it in a `List` then send your `List`. All the implementations like `ArrayList` already implement `Serializable` interface, you can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1387966/1065197) to know more about List Serialization.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could inherit from ResultSet and implement Serializable interfaces in a new class.
I would suggest a better approach would be to send XML between layers, or if you want an all Java solution, how about creating an object for each row, stuffing them in a collection class or vector, and serializing it instead of the ResultSet class.

Answer (score 1):

Since it needs to be serializable and send it across a network connection a [CachedRowSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/CachedRowSet.html) seems to be a good option for you to try.