# Android How to pass Object User to fragment from activity

Tags: android

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(Login.this, PlatformActivity.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("user",user);
                mIntent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(mIntent);

public class User implements Serializable {

    private List<UserAccount> userAccountList;
    ...
    ...
}
```

RuntimeException:Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.orbis.mobile.User)

User is not serializable , I want to know how to pass Object with arrayList. If user not set userAccountList, it can be worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            ArrayList<UserAccount> userAccountList = user.getUserAccountList();
            user.setUserAccountList(null);

            bundle.putSerializable("user", user);

            bundle.putSerializable("accountList", userAccountList);

            mIntent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(mIntent);


    user = (User) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("user");

    ArrayList<UserAccount> accountNumberList = (ArrayList<UserAccount>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("accountList");

    user.setUserAccountList(accountNumberList);
```

Answer (score 0):

`List` is not a `Serializable` interface, you need to use an implementation like `ArrayList`

See
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html

and
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

```
public class User implements Serializable {

    private ArrayList<UserAccount> userAccountList;
    ...
    ...
}
```

Also `UserAccount` needs to `implements Serializable`

Comment: List can be serialized, UserAccount object is throwing the exception.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1387966/2402866

Comment: @AlonLevanon that post you linked confirms what I said. `List` is not `serializable` `ArrayList` is.