# java.util.Set, java.util.List Serializable issue

Tags: java, collections, serializable

java.util.Set , java.util.List and other Collection interfaces are not serializable. Require a simple, direct solution to use this in a serializable POJO.

```
public class Employee implements Serializable{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Set<Address> address= new HashSet<Address>;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Serialize a list in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387954/how-to-serialize-a-list-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

HashSet is serializable [[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)] as long as all the objects it contains are serializable, so you need to make sure that `Address` class is serializable.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case there are two solutions. One is the approach used in the possible duplicate's answers. The other is to make the field type `HashSet<Address>` rather than `Set<Address>`. The field type should be the least specific type that supports all the features you intend to use.

Comment: Even with `Set<Address>` he should not get any error, if `Address` is serializable.