# Unable to Serialize Hashmap ,java.io.NotSerializableException

Tags: java, android

```
public class Common implements Serializable{

    private static HashMap<Integer,List<LevelList>> levelListMap = new HashMap<>();

    public static Map<Integer, List<LevelList>> getLevelListMap(Context context) {

        File file = new File(context.getDir("data", MODE_PRIVATE), "map");
        ObjectInputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            levelListMap = (HashMap<Integer, List<LevelList>>) inputStream.readObject();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return levelListMap;
    } ...
}
```

I am unable to serialize hashmap.I keep getting `java.io.NotSerializableException` for 
`levelListMap = (HashMap<Integer, List<LevelList>>) inputStream.readObject();`

```
public class LevelList implements Serializable{

    public int id;
    public String title;
    public String imgurl;
    public String songurl;
    public String songtext;
    boolean isFavourite;

    public void release() {

    }


    public void setFavourite(boolean favourite) {
        isFavourite = favourite;
    }

    public boolean isFavourite(){
        return isFavourite;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add stacktrace.

Comment: You must have got exactly the same exception when serializing, and you must have ignored it. Don't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HashMap` is serializable, but the keys and values must also be serializable. Make sure that all keys and values are serializable, and that their fields are also serializable (excluding transient and static members).

Edit:

`HashMap<Integer,List<LevelList>>`, is your `List` implementation serializable?

Comment: Yes I'm using ArrayList.Will it help ,if I change HashMap<Integer,List<LevelList>> to HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<LevelList>> ?

Comment: @sreejithvs No, it will help if you make `LevelList` implement `Serializable`. Clealry you hadn't done that when you did the serialization, and clearly you ignored the same exception at that point.

Answer (score 1):

Check this link [How to serialize a list in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387954/how-to-serialize-a-list-in-java). Standard implementation of List, i.e. ArrayList, LinkedList, etc. are serializable.

If you declare your List as one of the List subtypes such as `ArrayList<LevelList> levelList = new ArrayList<LevelList>();` then it should be serializable out of the box. Otherwise you will need to cast in a safe way, such as setting the List implementation with `<T extends List<Foo> & Serializable> setFooList(T list)` as suggested by [Theodore Murdock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1055489/theodore-murdock) in that answer thread.

Comment: "they need to first be casted to a Serializable type" - this statement is incorrect as the Serializable type check is done at runtime

Comment: @SteveKuo I will go ahead and revise that statement, thanks for pointing that out.