# Cast nested List<List<T>> to nested ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>

Tags: java, list, arraylist, casting

What's the best / most performant way to cast a `List<List<T>>` to `ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>`?

Let's assume I have an interface `IFoo.getListOfLists()` which will give me the `List<List<T>>`. Let's also assume I know that these `List<List<T>>` are in fact instances of `ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>`.

One simple solution would be:

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (List<T> arrayList : IFoo.getListOfLists()) {
        result.add((ArrayList<T>)arrayList);
    }
```

but is there a better approach? Especially, because I already know that the instances are in fact `ArrayList`s.

Comment: Why do you need `ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>` at the first place?

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis because `ArrayList` implements `Serializable` which `List` does not.

Comment: You might find this relevant. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387954/how-to-serialize-a-list-in-java

Comment: All standard implementations of java.util.List already implement java.io.Serializable. It's safe to cast if you are sure it's one of them.

Comment: Serializable is just a constraint of the interface I use. I don't really need it for this specific use-case. But thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since the type information for the `List` is absent at runtime, you can simply cast to `ArrayList`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CastListList {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final List<List<String>> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        strings.add(new ArrayList<>());
        strings.get(0).add("Hello World!");

        final ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arrayList = cast(strings);
        System.out.println(arrayList.get(0).get(0));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    private static <T> ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> cast(final List<List<T>> list) {
        return (ArrayList) list;
    }
}
```